# python sort list by custom criteria

Tags: python

I have following data read from csv :

```
venues =[{'capacity': 700, 'id': 1, 'name': 'AMD'},
{'capacity': 2000, 'id': 2, 'name': 'Honda'},
{'capacity': 2300, 'id': 3, 'name': 'Austin Kiddie Limits'},
{'capacity': 2000, 'id': 4, 'name': 'Austin Ventures'}]
```

i get the unique keys with :

```
b= list({k for d in venues for k in d.keys()})
```

which results in random order :

```
['name', 'capacity', 'id']
```

i would like to sort the unique key result in following manner :

```
sorted_keys = ['id','name','capacity']
```

how may i achieve this ?

Comment: whats the sorting criteria?

Comment: It should be sorted ['id','name','capacity']

Comment: You need to use `OrderedDict`

Comment: If you know that the output should be `['id','name','capacity']` why do you build it from input file instead of just defining `SORTED_KEYS=['id','name','capacity']`?

Answer (score 2):

In python tuples are sorted element-wise, so using a key function that produces tuple from your dictionaries should do the trick.

```
>>> sorted(venues, key=lambda row: (row['id'], row['name'], row['capacity']))
```

To be slightly more concise, you could use [operator.itemgetter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.itemgetter).

```
>>> from operator import itemgetter
>>> sorted(venues, key=itemgetter('id','name','capacity'))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `sort()` function and its property `key` to introduce specific criteria when sorting your list:

```
venues =[{'capacity': 700, 'id': 1, 'name': 'AMD'},
{'capacity': 2000, 'id': 2, 'name': 'Honda'},
{'capacity': 2300, 'id': 3, 'name': 'Austin Kiddie Limits'},
{'capacity': 2000, 'id': 4, 'name': 'Austin Ventures'}]

venues.sort(key=lambda x: x["capacity"])
print(venues)
```

**Output:** *In this case it sorts by capacity parameter*

```
[{'capacity': 700, 'id': 1, 'name': 'AMD'}, {'capacity': 2000, 'id': 2, 'name': 'Honda'}, {'capacity': 2000, 'id': 4, 'name': 'Austin Ventures'}, {'capacity': 2300, 'id': 3, 'name': 'Austin Kiddie Limits'}]
```

Also, you can sort unique keys as follows:

```
venues =[{'capacity': 700, 'id': 1, 'name': 'AMD'},
{'capacity': 2000, 'id': 2, 'name': 'Honda'},
{'capacity': 2300, 'id': 3, 'name': 'Austin Kiddie Limits'},
{'capacity': 2000, 'id': 4, 'name': 'Austin Ventures'}]

venues.sort(key=lambda x: (x["id"], x["name"], x["capacity"]))
print(venues)
```

Comment: Thank you , but i just need to sort the unique keys as im going to write it in another csv

Answer (score 0):

To get your sort order you could use name length as the key.

```
b = sorted(b, key=lambda x: len(x))
```

Comment: I don't think that's what the OP needs.

Comment: @Vishnudev I am judging mostly from the original title of the  post: 'python sort list by custom criteria'

Comment: Hmm.. Makes sense @Dmitri. Question is vaguely defined.

Comment: thats why I asked about the criteria